# How does CGContextFillPath in Objective C work?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, graphics, cgcontext

I have the following code which is supposed to draw a stroked and filled rectangle but the fill won't show up.

```
    [[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor brownColor] setFill];

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, right, bottom);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, right,top);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,left, top);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, left, bottom);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, right, bottom);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
```

The stroke works and I get a nice green rectangle with no fill (or a white fill).  This is within a UIView for iOS.  Seems very simple and it's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right way to do this is to set the drawing mode to include both a fill and a path.

```
CGPathDrawingMode mode = kCGPathFillStroke;
CGContextClosePath( context ); //ensure path is closed, not necessary if you know it is
CGContextDrawPath( context, mode );
```

You can use `CGContextFillPath()` to simply do a fill, but it's basically just `CGContextDrawPath()` that automatically calls `CGContextClosePath()` and uses `kCGPathFill` as the `CGPathDrawingMode`. You might as well always use `CGContextDrawPath()` and put in your own parameters to get the type of fill/stroke that you want. You can also put holes in convex paths by using one of the Even-Odd drawing modes.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs on [CGContextStrokePath](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html):

> Quartz uses the line width and stroke color of the graphics state to
>   paint the path. As a side effect when you call this function, Quartz
>   clears the current path.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should call   **CGContextClosePath** before you call **CGContextFillPath**

Comment: Nope, CGContextFillPath does this automatically.